# ValidationException: The provided starting key is invalid - What to put in ExclusiveStartKey - dynamodb

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am working with nodeJS, dynamo db and AWS API gateway, where I am new to dynamo db,

The requirement is of converting the response into pages, using pagination in my code,
so that from each API call, we got some pagination token and that can be passed from the UI, to get another set of response.

For that I have got the LastEvaluatedKey in object format, given below:

```
{
    "userName": {
        "S": "username"
    },
    "Id": {
        "S": "id-value"
    }
}
```

What I found is I need to set ExclusiveStartKey in following format:

```
ExclusiveStartKey = {
       "ID": {"S": LastEvaluatedKey}
};
```

On doing this, I am getting following error : **ValidationException: The provided starting key is invalid**.

Can someone please suggest, where I am going wrong, or what needs to be passed in ExclusiveStartKey value?

after edit:
added code :
my function:

```
var response = await dynamo.query(params).promise();

    if(response['Items'].length > 0) {
        addDataApps = [...addDataApps, ...response['Items']];
    }
    if (response.LastEvaluatedKey) {
        result = {
            addAppData: addDataApps,
            paginationToken: response.LastEvaluatedKey
         };
         return result;
    } else {
         result = {
            addAppData: addDataApps,
            paginationToken: null
          };
          return(result);
    }
```

and following is the response from postman

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "data":"data value"
        },
        {
           "data":"data value" 
        }
    ],
    "paginationToken": {
        "userName": {
            "S": "username"
        },
        "id": {
            "S": "id"
        }
    }
}
```

then I am doing this to assign it to startKey:

```
params.ExclusiveStartKey = {
       "ID": {"S": {
        "userName": {
            "S": "username"
        },
        "id": {
            "S": "id"
        }
    }}
     };
```

solution:
Its solved now, as I am new to dynamodb, I was not aware about the pagination working, somehow I found that the token I was passing was into string format, that was not accepted as a exclusiveStartKey, so I have converted the format into object adding the partition key and sort key of the table.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show us the code that's making the call. Are you getting the LastEvaluatedKey from a previous call? Are you successfully getting the first page of results? Please include the simplest code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: hi, @kevintechie, yes, I am getting the LastEvaluatedKey, please check the updated question,I have added the response getting and how I am assigning it to exclusive start key.

Comment: Please show ALL your code, not just snippets of the response. The response you show does not include the LastEvaluatedKey attribute. The value of this attribute is what must be passed to ExclusiveStartKey.

Comment: hi, @kevintechie, I have added code, please check and let me know, if any further detail is required form my end.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably benefit from this GitHub project that hosts a lot of sample code. Here are two Node.js examples showing pagination.

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/node.js/WorkingWithQueries/query-with-pagination-all-data.js

https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-dynamodb-examples/blob/master/DynamoDB-SDK-Examples/node.js/WorkingWithScans/scan-fetch-all-pagination.js

Comment: Hi, I have checked the git hub links, the issue is I am not using a recursive function flow as shown in code, I have to use the obtained pagination token in the request headers of the api call, and then assign it to the exclusiveStartKey,
When directly doing this :  params.ExclusiveStartKey = LastEvaluatedKey , I am getting another error i.e, InvalidParameterType: Expected params.ExclusiveStartKey to be a map

Comment: From the first link you can see how a successful request is put together, even without the recursion.